# Difference between height 100% in FireFox and everyone else

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to make several nested containers stretch to fill the page. I know there are ton's of questions and answers out there and every one has a different answer but none explain why this behavior exists.

Basically at some arbitrary point the "Height:100%" stops functioning and i have to switch over to "min-height:100%" and if i happen to have both present then the layout is massively screwed up.

I have a solution that works in IE11, FF(latest), and Chrome(latest) and one that works in the others but doesn't work in FF and i can't tell why.

Here is a JSFiddle explaining it, **but i'd like to note that JSFiddles display behavior doesn't match the browsers at all**  so i'm also going to try and write out the code. https://jsfiddle.net/2xa8rvek/

Basically here's what happens. Place a big block of content in the center that will not scroll when the window is large enough but will scroll when the window height is reduced. Then observe the different behavior based on which color is shown.

I will call **senario A** when the scrollbar is shown and the window is scrolled half way down.
I will call **senario B** when the page height is large enough that the bottom of the text block will be shown.

**Document**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="page-specific-container">
            <div class="content-middle">
                An arbitrary amount of content goes here that would force the screen to re-size if the user wasn't full screen. 
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16pt;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

#content-container{
    padding-top: 45px; /* This is for navigation */
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

#page-specific-container{
    /* At this point the "height" property alone no longer works with scrolling */
    /* Firefox requires that "height: 100%" also be present or else the .content-middle tag doesn't work */
    min-height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

.content-middle{
    /* If "Height:" is referenced here at all it will break the layout */
    min-height: 100%;
    background:purple;
}
```

Here's a rundown of the behavior:

-- height: 100% for #page-specific-container and .content-middle

------- Scenario A will show a blue strip at the bottom.

------- Scenario B will show purple all the way down.

-- min-height: 100% for #page-specific-container and .content-middle

------- Scenario A shows purple in all browsers.

------- Scenario B shows yellow in FF but shows purple in all other browsers.

-- min-height: 100% and height: 100% for #page-specific-container and just min-height:100%; for .content-middle

------- Scenario A will show purple all the way down.

------- Scenario B will show purple all the way down.

-- min-height: 100% and height: 100% for both #page-specific-container and .content-middle

------- Scenario A will show the blue color.

------- Scenario B will show purple only.

Why does FF behave differently? Why is there a random depth that Height: 100% no longer works?

EDIT: i would also like to note that this format of layout breaks any flexbox that is inside #page-specific-container

Comment: What do you mean by JSFiddles display behavior doesn't match the browsers at all. We're displaying the fiddle using the browsers. Are you saying that the result in JSFiddle is different from a .html file on your computer?

Comment: @MrLister Yes. The rendered output is different.